# How to rename an autogenerated n:m table in EF 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, many-to-many

I set up a database using EF 6. I configured a many-to-many relationship successfully with the code seen below:

```
public class Software
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Version { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Navigation property for machineSoftware
    public virtual ICollection<Machine> MachineSoftwares { get; set; }
}

public class Machine
{
    public int MachineId { get; set; }

    public string Model { get; set; }

    public string Customer { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Software> MachineSoftwares { get; set; }
}
```

EF 6 created a third table `MachineSoftwares` automatically. So far so good.

Now I want to rename that table, but I don't have a corresponding class for that table that I could rename via migration. So how can I rename the table `MachineSoftwares`?

Comment: You can simply write a new name instead of MachineSoftwares and do add-migration "MigrationName" and then update-database. Migration will automatically take care of renaming. You just need to give different name.

Comment: @noobprogrammer So in both classes change the name "MachineSoftwares"??

Comment: The property that you mentioned in above snippet (or class) would be used to establish the ForeignKey. Don't rename those. Go to the class where you have actually created 'MachineSoftwares' and written properties for it, rename it something and then process that I mentioned above.

Comment: Well, thats the point. I haven't created "MachineSoftwares". EF 6 created that table autoatically. So there is no class where I created that table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name of the implicit many-to-many junction table (and the names of its columns) are configured through the `Map` Fluent API.

But in order to get access to that API, you have to first map the relationship using a `HasMany` / `WithMany` pair:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Software>()
    .HasMany(e => e.MachineSoftwares)
    .WithMany(e => e.MachineSoftwares)
    .Map(config => config
        .ToTable("the_desired_table_name")
        //.MapLeftKey("SoftwareId") // in case you need different column names
        //.MapRightKey("MachineId")
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add Table attribute to your code, EF have more options for attributes, for example the name of column:

```
[Table("custom_name_table")]
public class Software
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Column("the_version_name")]
    public string Version { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Navigation property for machineSoftware
    public virtual ICollection<Machine> MachineSoftwares { get; set; }
}
```

check this link https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/table-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx